# phpmailer send to multiple emails including unique unsubscribe link

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am making php script to send newsletter with option to unsubscribe for each recipient.

The code below works - sends and email to each subscriber which i have in DB. However it adds unsubscribe links to everyone. So if i have 2 subscribers they both get same message body AND 2 links to unsubcscribe.

Here is the code.

```
if (isset($_POST['sendemail'])) {
    require_once "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php";
    require_once "phpmailer/class.smtp.php";
    $message = "TEST MESSAGE";
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $body = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$message);
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Host = "myserver";
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->Username = "myuser";
    $mail->Password = "mypass";
    $mail->SMTPDebug = false;
    $mail->do_debug = 0;
    $mail->SetFrom("me@domain.ltd", "Me");
    $mail->AddReplyTo("me@domain.ltd", "Me");
    $mail->AddAddress("some@email.com", "member");
    // I GET LIST OF SUBSCRIBED EMAILS AND LOOP THE MAIL SENDING
    $result = dbquery("SELECT * FROM emails WHERE email_sub='1'");
    while($row = dbarray($result)) {
        // HERE SHOULD BE ONIQUE UNSUBSCRIBE LINKO FOR EACH EMAIL
        $body .= "<br /><a href=\"http://someurl.tld/emails.php?email=".$row["email_address"]."\">Unsubscribe</a>";
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->MsgHTML($body);
        $mail->WordWrap = 50;
        $mail->AddBCC($row["email_address"], $row["email_name"]);
        $mail->addCustomHeader("List-Unsubscribe","<admin@keepity.com>, <http://keepity.com/?email=".md5(md5($row["email_address"])).">");
    }
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "<i class=\"fa fa-warning\"></i> Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo."<br />";
    } else {
        echo "Done";
    }
}
```

so email looks like this

```
Message body.....

Unsubscribe
Unsubscribe
```

So if i had 100 subscribers there would be 100 links in each email..

Comment: you are set send function outside the while loop

Comment: sidenote: `eregi_replace()` that's deprecated. use `preg_replace()`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
$body = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$message);
```

this code should be inside the while loop.
What you are doing wight now is to append the unsubscribe link the the present value of $body, which in loop keep on adding a new unsubscribe link each time .

So the number of times the loop executes, it will keep adding one more unsubscribe link in addition to what is already there.

Final Code..

```
if (isset($_POST['sendemail'])) {
    require_once "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php";
    require_once "phpmailer/class.smtp.php";
    $message = "TEST MESSAGE";
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Host = "myserver";
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->Username = "myuser";
    $mail->Password = "mypass";
    $mail->SMTPDebug = false;
    $mail->do_debug = 0;
    $mail->SetFrom("me@domain.ltd", "Me");
    $mail->AddReplyTo("me@domain.ltd", "Me");
    $mail->AddAddress("some@email.com", "member");
    // I GET LIST OF SUBSCRIBED EMAILS AND LOOP THE MAIL SENDING
    $result = dbquery("SELECT * FROM emails WHERE email_sub='1'");
    while($row = dbarray($result)) {
        $body = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$message);
        // HERE SHOULD BE ONIQUE UNSUBSCRIBE LINKO FOR EACH EMAIL
        $body .= "<br /><a href=\"http://someurl.tld/emails.php?email=".$row["email_address"]."\">Unsubscribe</a>";
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->MsgHTML($body);
        $mail->WordWrap = 50;
        $mail->AddBCC($row["email_address"], $row["email_name"]);
        $mail->addCustomHeader("List-Unsubscribe","<admin@keepity.com>, <http://keepity.com/?email=".md5(md5($row["email_address"])).">");
    }
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "<i class=\"fa fa-warning\"></i> Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo."<br />";
    } else {
        echo "Done";
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not help much. Yes it send 1 link to all. But link is incorrect. All recipients receive same link. But it should be their email.

Answer (score 0):

This you are sending two links :

1. InMessage body: 
   2.Inside header
    , http://url_to_unscribe.com

here is an example how it should be called :

```
  $mail->addCustomHeader("List-Unsubscribe",'<admin@keepity.com>, <http://keepity.com/?email='.$address.'>');
```